# Unittesing stringified JSON

Tags: python, json, string, unit-testing

I have a function that looks something like

```
def function_to_test(data):
    data = some_operations_inline(data)
    return stringify_json(data)
```

where

```
def stringify_json(data):
    return json.dumps(data, encoding='utf-8')
```

I want to unit test `function_to_test` (with `tox` + `nose`). The problem is that ordering of the elements inside the string changes with the `PYTHONHASHSEED`.

I tried to change the function to:

```
def stringify_json(data):
    sorted_dict = OrderedDict([[k, v] for k, v in sorted(data.items())])
    return json.dumps(sorted_dict, encoding='utf-8')
```

But this does not help if the `data` contains another `dict`.

How do I test it? The obvious thing would be to do compare the json values, and not their string versions:

```
self.assertEqual(
    json.loads(expected),
    json.loads(computed)
)
```

Would that be acceptable? Even if I am not testing the real function output? I guess we can assume that `json.dumps` was already tested.
Note: I wrapped `json.dumps` so I could make sure that all the dumps are done consistently.

Comment: You could write another version of `dump` that does the sorting itself. Dumping is pretty easy if done recursively.

Comment: It looks like you want to unittest them`json` package instead of your function. A unittest should test the function and mock all dependencies. Testing the Python standard lib is not the job of a unittest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I test it? The obvious thing would be to do compare the json
>   values, and not their string versions:
>
> ```
> self.assertEqual(
>     json.loads(expected),
>     json.loads(computed)
> )
> ```
>
> Would that be acceptable? Even if I am not testing the real function
>   output?

You *are* testing the real function output. It's not like you plugged fake output into the second `json.loads` call. You are confirming that the output has the required properties: specifically, that the output deserializes to the correct data.

Using `json.loads` here is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own dump function:

```py
def sorted_json_dump(x):
    if isinstance(x, str):
        return '"{}"'.format(repr(x)[1:-1])
    elif isinstance(x, list):
        return "[{}]".format(", ".join(sorted_json_dump(i) for i in x))
    elif isinstance(x, dict):
        return "{{{}}}".format(", ".join(
            "{}: {}".format(
                repr(str(sorted_json_dump(k)))[1:-1],
                sorted_json_dump(v)
            )
            for k, v in sorted(x.items(), key = lambda i: i[0])
        ))
    else:
        return repr(x)
```

Comment: True, but this seems to create another problem in order to solve mine